# Missing data for data analysis

Tags: sql, postgresql, geolocation, data-analysis, data-cleaning

I have a rookie question. I'm cleaning a dataset and have encountered some missing location data. While I have the coordinates data, attempting to reverse it into location names has proven to be inaccurate and would hinder my analysis. Are there any alternative approaches to processing this data without relying on reversing the coordinates? n

Note that my dataset contains approximately 6 million rows, making manual processing impossible.

I've tried the reverse geocoding method but it's not working. I need other approaches. This is my first time facing this type of data.

Comment: Hi - what coordinate data? What location data are you trying to generate? In what way is your reverse geocoding method not working? Sample data, required outcome and your attempt at solving the issue are always a good start when asking a question

Comment: If your location data is of datatype geometry ([PostGIS extension](https://postgis.net/), coordinates could be transformed into it) you could find location names (instead of reverse geocoding) by using intersection or contained in functions with other geometric objects (such as lines representing streets or polygons representing neighborhoods, municipalities or other type of areas).